# How to sense the current an amplifier is supplying?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, current-sensing

Consider the circuit below. It is made up of three parts: input, bidirectional amplifier, and output. If we set the gain of the amplifier to 1, then it as if we've just connected the input to the output directly.

The bidirectional amplifier is composed of a VCVS (E1) and a CCCS (B1). The reason I'm using a CCCS with a VCVS is because while I want to amplify the voltage, I also want the input to feel the effect of the load. This is why B1 produces a current proportional to the current through the load.

[image]

With the above explanation, I'm now trying to implement the bidirectional amplifier using real components. At the moment, I'm focusing on functionality, and ignoring nonlinearity, how much the gain I can get, etc.

A first attempt is the circuit below. It has voltage amplifer with M1 and M2. This part is straighforward. Now, I need to sense the current supplied by the amlplifier when it is connected to a load. I was thinking of implementing the current amplifier with a transconductance amplifier. That is, I somehow measure the current through the load, convert it to voltage, and then use a MOS transistor to produce the current. The question is how do I sense the current? The attempt below does not work since the node A2 is fixed.

[image]

Comment: Why not replicate R1 across A1 and ground <-- doesn't that do the same?

Comment: I don't exactly I undertsand what you mean, but R1 is supposed to control the gain.

Comment: I can only read your question. That's all the info I have; you didn't mention anything about what R1 is meant to do. The only 3 instances of R1 appearing in text is in these comments.

Comment: just find a very small resistor(milliohm) and  connect it in series to your load and finally measure the voltage across to get the current output?